# 3 stage interaction with a form select not working in IE11

Tags: jquery, css, forms, select, internet-explorer-11

I wrote a specific 3 stage interaction which I thought was working fine until I opened in IE11 and it was way off. I'm missing some styling but the main components are here:

http://codepen.io/szyam/pen/bflLw

here is my jquery:

```
$('#share select').change( function(){
    $('.fill-out').addClass('goodbye');
    $('.start').addClass('goodbye');
    $('#share .share').css('left','0');
});
$('#back').click(function() {
    $('.fill-out').removeClass('goodbye').css('left','0');
    $('#share .share').css('left','600');
});
```

I'm somewhat new to writing my own custom jQuery so I'm betting there is a better way to script this.

It's somewhat self explanatory but the idea is the visitor hovers over the box, a select comes into view, that select one of the option and on change a new slide slides in with a few link choices on where they want to share their data with.

Any idea's why it's not working or improvement suggestions are welcome.

Comment: So what actually happens in IE 11?

Comment: The select kind of keeps resetting itself and doesn't actually select and move to the next slide. It also seems to get repositioned. I'll try to make some screenshots.